# Why GST carries weight in property price?

Tags: real-estate, rental-property, gst, new-zealand

Country is New Zealand. Some properties in the market carry a message,

> This property is worth xxx,xxx dollars (plus GST if any)

I am really confused by this "plus GST if any" statement. If GST applies, well it applies. Why is this statement ambiguous? It sounds like there are two possibilities even there is only one property.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently GST can only apply to properties used for commercial purposes (and not where the vendor uses it as a principal place of residence).

Whether or not GST applies also depends on the combination of whether the vendor or purchaser or both are registered for GST.

It appears to be complicated; other factors make a difference too. There's [an explanation here](http://www.prlaw.co.nz/article/83/111/GST-and-Property-Transactions/).

You would probably be best asking for an explanation from the vendor or real estate agent, and then verifying it with the IRD (or a lawyer).